# Dataset with additional columns. These are not recognized when I update the data source. How to update the existing data source

Tags: powerbi, dataset, refresh, powerbi-desktop

### **PROBLEM**

I have a pretty simple Set-Up:

- Power BI Report
- Data Source csv with 14 Columns

Now I received an update of the csv

- with **additional 5 columns**
- new columns are a attached "in the middle of the table" as column 2 to 6.
- When I exchange the data file and refresh the data source Power BI does only load the Colums 1 to 14 and ignores the columns 15 to 19

[image]

---

### **WHAT I ALREADY TRIED:**

- Update Data --> Error message "Missing Columns"
- Data transformation > Datasource settings > reselect dataset file --> Error message "Missing Columns"
- Data transformation > Power Query Editor > Step "Source" > reselect dataset file --> Error message "Missing Columns"
- Data transformation > Power Query Editor > Step "Source" > update Dax by changing the delimiter from 14 to 19 --> **that did the job**

> = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:...............\daten.csv"),[Delimiter=";",
> Columns=**14**, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])

to

> = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:...............\daten.csv"),[Delimiter=";",
> Columns=**19**, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])

---

### Question

Is their any other more convenient way to update a dataset with addition rows?

Comment: Can you post your full query from advanced editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one-

Change source

Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:...............\daten.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=14, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),

Remove **Columns** parameter:

Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:...............\daten.csv"), [Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])

Comment: make sure  that 'Changed type' command goes after 'Promoted header'